# Laravel ajax request get the id from the table pass it to button edit

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-6

hello i'm trying to make ajax crud not using package only Jquery as library, i can load the data to the table no issue, only problem i have is when i want to edit the data i'm trying to pass the ID to the edit button but problem is only one button work i can only get one id, and when i click the rest it isn't working.

**Ajax code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#my').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ URL::route('sample') }}",
            type:'get',
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:'application/json',
            success:function (data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#data').html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, val){
                    $('#data').append("<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+val.id+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+val.name+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+val.code+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+val.user.name+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<button class='btn btn-warning' id='edit' data-id="+val.id+" value="+val.id+">Edit</button>"+
                            "<button class='btn btn-danger' id='delete' data-id="+"ssasaa"+">Delete</button>"
                        +"</td>"+
                    +"</tr>")

                    $('#edit').click(function(event){
                        id=$(this).val();
                        console.log(id);
                    })
                    $('#delete').click(function(){
                        console.log('button delete click');
                    })

                })

            },

            error:function(err){
                    console.log('Error loading data')
                 }

        });/*==End of Ajax==*/


    });
            });
```

**Console result**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the jquery click handler is targeting an ID:

```
 $('#my').on('click'...
```

In HTML, ids must be unique. Only one element can have the id "my"

Change your `id="my"` on all your html buttons to a class like `class='my'` then change your jquery to:

```
 $('.my').on('click'...
```

### Looking deeper

you most likely need to convert the `$('#edit')` and `$('#delete')` to classes as well but its hard to know for sure without seeing the html

### Also

I see you said you're doing this with no packages and just jquery, that said, Id recommend looking into [Backpack for laravel](https://backpackforlaravel.com/) which would make this super easy to build once set up :)